# When calling api url in ionic 2 ,am getting this error:No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am using ionic 2 get method ,when i am calling the api its showing like this .Please help me to fix this issue.Even if i give headers also am facing same problem

> Failed to load http. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your server doesn't support Cross origin request.
You can install cors package on your server.

If you are using Node.Js, then you can simply install cors from npm and import it in Node.

Comment: Am using ionic 2 with angular js 2 for that how to install and import ,can you send me the plugin,because i thought this is server side backend issue,if they add headers means this issue wont happens for us.

Comment: It's a server side issue. You have to install cors package on server only.

Comment: Php team only have to add headers right.Its not front side mistake right.They have to add headers in route correct or not

Comment: Yeah Kalai. Server side team can easily accomplish this things. You can also try the hack posted by DotNet Dreamer.

Answer (score 0):

This is common CORS issue. You can read more about it in wiki. If you are using `ionic server` command then, there are two solutions, either allow CORS on server, if you don't have access to server then you can use ionic CLI proxy. Just add the following to your `ionic.config.json` file in the root directory of you project.

```
  "proxies": [{
    "path": "/myapi/",
    "proxyUrl": "http://example.com/apiurl/"
  }]
```

Now in your code you instead of absolute url to your api, you can use the `/myapi/` as a URL. if you want to remove the `/` then omit it from both URLs. 
After this change, you need to restart your `ionic serve` command.
Please note that, if you are using `iOS` new version of ionic uses [wkwebview](https://ionicframework.com/docs/wkwebview/)
.
 so in that case in device, you still need to allow cors on your server.

Comment: already i given this code in ionic.config.js file,in path and proxyUrl what i have to given either my base url or which one i have to given

Comment: @kalaivani can you share your ionic.config.json code ? and what url you are using in your code ?

Comment: code:
  "name": "helloWorld",
  "app_id": "",
  "type": "ionic-angular",
  "integrations": {
    "cordova": {}
  }
 "proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/api",
      "proxyUrl": "http://cors.api.com/api"
    }
  ]
  } . if i give like this issue showing,its not valid json format.My url is "http://schoolwyse.net"

Comment: no, in your code you need to use `/api` instead of `http://cors.api.com/api`. also `http://cors.api.com/api` should be your real api URL. no need to add the word `cors` or something else to it. Just a simple url pointing to your  api

Comment: code format showing invalid json.in path i have to give /api and in proxy i have to give http://schollwyse.net right.check my code its showing invalid json format

Comment: @kalaivani share your all code after the update, you might have forgotten `,` somewhere

Comment: {
  "name": "helloWorld",
  "app_id": "",
  "type": "ionic-angular",
  "proxies": [{
    "path": "/myapi/",
    "proxyUrl": "http://schoolwyse.net/"
  }],
  "integrations": {
    "cordova": {}
  }

} now its running but same issue only i am facing access control allow origin

Comment: @kalaivani it seems fine, but the url `schoolwyse.net` is pointing to your website and not your api. It should be your api.

Comment: yes but this is base url right.api url  i have many .i have to give all api url,how its possible

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while using woocommerce api and i found one temporary hack to this which i read it on ionic forum while finding a solution, by installing this plugin on chrome
[Allow-Control-Allow-Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en)